# jQuery & IE on Refresh/Reload

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, refresh, reload

Basically I create a page with a jQuery scroller on it.
However in IE7 specifically, on refresh all the `li's` on the page are shown full out
then they hide and the scroller begins.

Anyone know how I can fire the jquery first, or prevent this from happening.

Heres the code

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/site/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/site/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1c4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".air_ticker").jCarouselLite({vertical: true,visible: 1,auto:10000,speed:1800});
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: It may have some accessibility issues, but have you thought about hiding the content with .css then using your java script to unhide it after setting the scroller properties. You could for example give the scroller a large negative left margin then move it on screen.

Comment: hmm..by doing so the text will look like it never disappears? Nor will it show all the li's real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way: like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855998/jquery-how-to-hide-divs-they-are-showing-for-a-split-second-on-page-load/1856038#1856038)

In your HTML:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.className += " js";
  </script>
```

In your CSS (loaded before the `.air_ticker` element appears in the HTML)

```
.js .air_ticker { display: none; }
```

Now, if the browser has JS, the `.air_ticker` element will be hidden before it has a chance to show.

Comment: Doing this keeps the elements entirely hidden. On refresh in IE I just dont want the li's shown for that second. I don't want to hide them permanently