# jQuery .hide doesn't hide elements fast enough

Tags: jquery, performance, hide

When I use `.hide()` with jQuery, it doesn't hide elements fast enough. I can see them all loading and being organized for another script that is also running. It looks really awkward.

Is there anyway to make `.hide()` actually hide elements before the document loads? I don't want to do display:none since this would hurt SEO.

Comment: .hide() sets the css style `display` to `none`...

Comment: This SO answer] may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855998/jquery-how-to-hide-divs-they-are-showing-for-a-split-second-on-page-load/1856038#1856038

Comment: if you want to hide an element before loading why don't you do it with CSS instead of Javascript?? That will be fast.

Comment: display none and .hide() is as mentioned above basicly the same thing. If it annoys you so much you could use css opacity, or set css position or margins or anything else you can think of to move the element off screen and then move it into the screen when the document is loaded. Seems like a lot of trouble to avoid display none though, and the display none solution is fairly cross browser as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can't do anything before the document completes at least a partial load - that's how the ready() function works.  However, you could use plain JavaScript executed before the jQuery ready function to hide the element you want hidden.  Search engines typically ignore JavaScript, so you'd be safe.

Since we're talking about JavaScript... is the "stuff" you're hiding loaded in by scripts or is it static (in the context of the loaded document)?  If the content is being loaded in by Ajax, I'm not sure a search engine would see it anyway, in which case you might just want to hide it with CSS and be done with it.

Comment: I suppose you can run jQuery without the ready() function... but it's likely to (may) run too quickly and miss elements of you page and therefore not work correctly.  Use plain JavaScript - no waiting!

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling the `hide()` method? On the document ready? Maybe adding the call to the `hide()` method directly after inserting the html for the element?

Something like:

```
 <div id="element">your element</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> $("#element").hide(); </script>
```